# Another Question on How to Cover Up Exposed Insulation in A Basement Ceiling

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

I have read through many questions with a similar problem, but different circumstances than I have regarding this issue.

The home is in Ohio so cold winters and hot summers built in 1997. I have a mostly finished basement with a workout room. I want to use the finished space for the workout room for another purpose. I have an unfinished storage area I can move my workout equipment into.  This area has lots of overhead pipes I need access to, and finishing it with drywall is not practical. Drop ceiling is not an option (even the ones that only drop it 1 1/2").

The home has a radiant heat system with boiler, so the insulation is there for those reasons although I have installed a geothermal system and don't utilize the radiant heat system any more. The basement is conditioned and has a vent in the unfinished area.  I don't normally run the heat downstairs, and it stays around 65-68 degrees F.

The unfinished room has 1 1/2" foamboard insulation installed on the walls. It is glued to the concrete and taped at seams.

My concern is breathing the fiberglass dust from the exposed ceiling insulation while working out over time.

I am not wanting to create any kind of mold problems, but would like to staple fire retardant plastic over the exposed insulation to limit the insulation dust.  Anyone see an issue with doing this? It is only for dust limiting. It will not be tightly stapled to make any kind of tight seal (maybe stapled every 6-8").

I have seen lots of similar questions but the seem to be in unconditioned basements.

I also could use Tyvek house wrap, but it is flammable and am not looking to break any fire codes.  I saw Tyvek has a flame resistant version, but could only find it offered in the United Kingdom.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Plastic would seal that space and possibly create a bigger issue with mold. If I was concerned I might get a HEPA type of air filter to circulate the air down there. turn it on before you go down and after you come up. I have worked in construction most of my life and don’t know of any issues I have installed and demoed many homes insulation and have quite a friends that do the same and I am not aware of problems, most of us only wear a dust mask if anything when installing batts or rolls, usually a mask when blowing it in. But a simple air recirculating filter would probably be best.

Comment: I will add a HEPA air filter in the room too. I think I will put the TYVEK covering on the ceiling to help brighten the area and to keep the fiberglass from falling excessively if I decide to bring a fan in during workouts. I know it most likely violates fire code, but it is just a small portion of my basement. I'll add a fire detector and CO monitor in the room and be done with it most likely. thanks for the suggestion.